# Query Recommendation with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create some query recommendation for query typed by the users with elasticsearch. The case is when users type `beac`, they will instantly get some recommendation such as `beach wedding`, `beach party`, `beach pool` and so on. Then, I have a list of documents that contain id, title, and its description. Those data have been indexed to elasticsearch.

My question is, is it possible to get the recommended query/phrase from the content of my indexed documents? Or is it better to have a list of possible queries that will be searched by the user and put them to the elasticsearch in a separate index and type?

Answer (score 0):

Yes is no A or B answer to this question. It depends a lot on what the users are looking for. It is based on current news, it is product data, is it twitter feed. You have to think about the content you have, does it change over time, does it have to take topicality into account or is it a more or less fixed set of data. In both situations the suggest API can help you a lot with finding suggestions based on terms, the technical side does not change for the specific index or the search terms from others index.

Hope that helps.